# Redirect to secondary site with login headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, svn, visualsvn-server

I'm working on a project for our employees to log in and manage certain things. We have an internal SVN server using VisualSVN that has its own web interface for browsing repositories, history, etc. I want to use that instead of reinventing the wheel. I'll be using ASP.NET. I can either provide a link or redirect to it just fine, no problem. But I'd like to not require the user to login again. They've already logged in to the employee portal.

The web interface uses BASIC authentication and so I've explored `Server.Transfer` to pass headers to the new server but the problem is I won't necessarily know what the user's password is. It may be different for SVN than for the portal. I have a Windows service running on the SVN server to manage certain aspects using the PowerShell cmdlets that are included. With this I can manage users and allow them to change their password, username, etc. So I could retrieve these values.

VisualSVN's web interface runs on top of Apache HTTP Server so I'm wondering if there's some way to use those values in the authentication header.

Or if there's a better way, I'm open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: Have you considered [Integrated Windows Authentication (Active Directory Single Sign-On)](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/windows-auth/)? Users will authenticate to VisualSVN Server automatically with their domain credentials without logon prompts.

Comment: We're using standard edition as we're a small enough company we don't have Active Directory. And Windows Authentication is not available in the Standard edition.